# VSTS extension - Create and run build definition

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines

I'm developing VSTS plugin in Javascript. As part of it, I need to build and run a task on any agent.

The flow is: Run build -> Wait the build to finish -> Click on a button -> Another different task is built and run.

I found a build REST client that [create build definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/reference/client/api/tfs/build/restclient/buildhttpclient2_1?view=vsts#createdefinition()) and [queue builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/reference/client/api/tfs/build/restclient/buildhttpclient2_1?view=vsts#queuebuild()).

I didn't find any examples nor any detailed documentation. Does anyone have a simple example that creates and runs a new build definition using that build REST client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's already such extensions to queue/trigger build tasks in Marketplace.

You can refer to below link to get the extensions:

- [Queue Build(s) Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jb.queue-build)
- [Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks)

If you want to develop your own extension, then you can reference the [source code of the extension **Trigger Build Task** on GitHub](https://github.com/huserben/TfsExtensions/blob/master/BuildTasks/Tfs15.md)